# Push Mercurial subrepo to the same path as its parent

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

Is there any way to configure Mercurial to push a subrepository to the same path specified when pushing its parent?

Say we have a parent repo with a subrepo, and the subrepo also has its own subrepo:

```
A
- B
- - C
```

Now, in each of A, B, and C we have alternate paths specified:

A .hg/hgrc

```
[paths]
default = http://path.to.default/A
devMachine = ssh://user@dev.machine/A
```

B .hg/hgrc

```
[paths]
default = http://path.to.default/B
devMachine = ssh://user@dev.machine/A/B
```

C .hg/hgrc

```
[paths]
default = http://path.to.default/C
devMachine = ssh://user@dev.machine/A/B/C
```

If I have unpublished changesets in A, B, and C, that I do not want to push to the central repository, but I DO want to push them between my Work & Home dev machines, is there any way I can set up Mercurial such that when I do `hg push devMachine` it will push B and C to `devMachine` as well, rather than pushing A to `devMachine` and pushing both B and C to `default`?

What I have been doing thus far is setting the new-commit phase to `secret` and doing:

```
$ cd A/B/C
A/B/C$ hg phase -d
A/B/C$ hg push devMachine
A/B/C$ hg phase -sf
A/B/C$ cd ..
A/B$ hg phase -d
A/B$ hg push devMachine
A/B$ hg phase -sf
A/B$ cd ..
A$ hg phase -d
A$ hg push devMachine
A$ hg phase -sf
```

For obvious reasons this is less than optimal. It would be much nicer if doing `A$ hg push devMachine` would recursively push all subrepos to the `devMachine` path (given that it has been defined in .hg/hgrc of course).

I know I could script this pretty easily. I'm just curious if Mercurial has something built-in that will do this that I haven't been able to find.

Answer (score 0):

> I DO want to push them between my Work & Home dev machines, is there
>   any way I can set up Mercurial such that when I do hg push devMachine
>   it will push B and C to devMachine as well, rather than pushing A to
>   devMachine and pushing both B and C to default?

Well, it works this way using TortoiseHg. The **hgrc** path section was set the same way you described. But the path alias was not being used in the call.

Log output was: `hg push some-real-absolute-path`

Instead of `hg push devMachine`, try `hg push ssh://user@dev.machine/A`

About the phases, in every repository of the Work(and/or Home) machine, add to **hgrc**:

```
[phases]
publish = False
```

Then commits will change to **public** phase, only when pushing to the central repository.

I advise to **NOT** use:

```
[phases]
new-commit = secret
```

Secret phase doesn't mix that well in subrepositories. I would only use it in the root repository.

Comment: No, this is not how it works in TortoisHG (at least not v 4.6.1 for macOS). I just tried it. When I push, it will push A to 'ssh://user@dev.machine/A', as expected, then it does 'pushing subrepo B to http://path.to.default/B'. A mercurial `[path]` is just an alias, so I don't see any reason why explicitly using a path would make a difference anyways.

Comment: This works for TortoiseHg 4.6.2 on Linux. I made some repositories just to test this, and they work fine here.

Comment: Huh, sounds like there's a discrepancy between macOS & Linux in the implementation. Too bad for me.